# Use a column to determine line width/size in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table with three columns - `dates`, `rates`, `balances`, I try to plot the rate changes but at the same time, I want the line width to reflect the aggregated balances for each day. If it's not easy to solve this problem. Is there any way I can use the total aggregated balances (sum balances) to represent the line width?

```
ID     DATES         RATES     BALANCES
 1     2000/01/01     0.5       100
 2     2000/01/01     0.25       50
 3     2000/01/01     0.1        25 
 1     2000/01/02     0.01      120
 2     2000/01/02     0.02      130
 3     2000/01/02     0.03      140
```

I am using `ggplot2` to plot the line chart for this

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dates, y=rates, group = id)) + geom_line()
```

however, I need to use the line width to reflect the aggregated balances (total balances of each day). How can I do this?

Comment: So if for one ID, balance on day 1 is 100 and balance on day 2 is 150, how would you intend to display the size of a line between them? You want the line to scale wider between these two dates? If so, check out `ggforce`'s `..index..`

Comment: ideally, the line width could change with IDs. If not, the line width can only reflect the aggregate value of each day, in this case, each id should have the same line width on the same day. the line width could only be used to reflect the aggregate balance of that specific day. thank you!